# Patrol point reversal

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working on a little Unity game, currently using a series of patrol points to move some objects about. This is the code I'm more or less using:

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, patrolPoints [currentPoint].position, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

I feel silly, maybe just burned out brain, but how would i reverse this so it goes from the highest point in the patrol to the lowest point? Tried this to no avail:

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, patrolPoints [currentPoint - 1].position, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: If currentPoint is intialized with either patrolPoints.Length for an array or patrolPoints.Count for a List it should work. What problem does "tried this to no avail" describe? More specific please.

Comment: It describes my method to have the objects move backwards on the array list of patrol points once it reaches the end. I have an array sized 3, have object move from the first, to second and end at third point. Then the second code lines meant to force it to go back 1 from the current point (and repeat if the conditions for triggering the move are still true ect). Less fuzzy headed now when typing this, but still in a burned out fugue, sorry if I'm not being clear.

Comment: @NateCraft If my answer solved your issue could you please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark? It allows other people who come to the question to quickly see an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Your question is very ambiguous but I will attempt to answer.

*Assuming* you mean how to go forwards and backwards through your list of `patrolPoints`:

**Define** your variables at the **top of the script.**

```
//List of patrolpoints
public Transform[] patrolPoints;
//To go forwards or backwards
public bool forwards = true;
//Current position
public int currentPoint = 0;
```

*Then* in your `Update()` function, we can **use** the **code you've presented**.

```
        float moveSpeed = 5.0f;
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, patrolPoints[currentPoint].position, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

*However*, we need some way to **cycle through these positions**, so **after your previous** code in `Update()`, write

```
        //Check if the agent has reached the patrol point
    if(transform.position == patrolPoints[currentPoint].position)
    {
        //Check if going forwards and has not reached last patrol
        if (forwards && currentPoint != patrolPoints.Length - 1)
            currentPoint++;
        //Check if going backwards and has not reached first patrol point
        else if (!forwards && currentPoint != 0)
            currentPoint--;
    }
```

*Then* change the forwards and backwards boolean to go forwards and backwards. **Alternatively** if you want to go straight back to the start patrolpoint directly, just use the code (in `Update()`):

```
        float moveSpeed = 5.0f;
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, patrolPoints[0].position, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Which uses `0` as the index.

Edit: If you want it to go **backwards once you've reached the end** just switch the **forwards variable to false** when currentPoint has reached the lastPoint. **Therefore**, the `update` function would be:

```
    void Update()
{
    float moveSpeed = 5.0f;
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, patrolPoints[currentPoint].position, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    //Check if the agent has reached the patrol point
    if(transform.position == patrolPoints[currentPoint].position)
    {
        //Check if going forwards and has not reached last patrol
        if (forwards && currentPoint != patrolPoints.Length - 1)
            currentPoint++;
        //Check if going forwards and has reached the last patrol
        if (forwards && currentPoint == patrolPoints.Length - 1)
            forwards = false;
        //Check if going backwards and has not reached first patrol point
        else if (!forwards && currentPoint != 0)
            currentPoint--;
        //And to go back if reached back to the start
        else if (!forwards && currentPoint == 0)
            forwards = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the response. I know I'm a bit late hehe. But yes, this worked and has helped me advance, thank you.